# Number of Observations in Regression

Tags: r, regression

How can i find out how many observations were used in a regression?

```
    model_simple <- as.formula("completion_yesno ~  ac + ov + UCRate + FirstWeek + LastWeek + DayofWeekSu + DayofWeekMo + DayofWeekTu + DayofWeekWe + DayofWeekTh + DayofWeekFr + MonthofYearJan + MonthofYearFeb + MonthofYearMar + MonthofYearApr +MonthofYearMay+ MonthofYearJun + MonthofYearJul + MonthofYearAug + MonthofYearSep + MonthofYearOct + MonthofYearNov")
clog_simple1 = glm(model_simple,data=cllw,family = binomial(link = cloglog))
summary(clog_simple1)
```

I have tried the `fitted` command which did not result in a concrete number of observations N

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the built in `nobs()` function

```
nobs(clog_simple1)
```

Comment: clog_simple1 is the variable on which we running the regression line ? for example `c <- ggplot(data, aes(x=GS, y=COA)) + geom_point(shape=1) + geom_smooth(method=lm , color="yellow", se=TRUE) + xlab("GS") + ylab("COA")
ggMarginal(c, type="histogram")` c is clog_simple1 ?

Comment: Thank you for the update, `Error in nobs.default(c) : no 'nobs' method is available`

Comment: @AHF For some reason that was edited out of the original question. `clog_simple1` is the value returned from `glm`. This method does not work with ggplot. If you want to work with the results of an model, you should fit it outside of ggplot. ggplot is just for ease of visualization.

Comment: fit outside of ggplot?

Comment: @AHF Yes, call `lm()` directly. This data is not readily available from `geom_smooth`.

Comment: +1, in case anyone tries `nobs` on `coxph` object, it returns the number of events, not the number of observations, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535088/the-bic-is-different-in-cph-and-coxph-for-the-same-model)